# null return value from getParameter (Tomcat Servlet)

Tags: java, html, ajax, servlets, post

I am trying to get the value of a checkbox from a posted form data.  I already have the form working because I can get the value of a file easily enough(I have omitted the file form field in the code below), but the checkbox wont return anything other than null.  What am I doing wrong?

Servlet:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String str = request.getParameter("isTransform");

    System.out.println("parameter: " + str);
}
```

Html Client:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="compareForm1" >
    <input type="checkbox" value="true" name="isTransform" id="isTransform1" >
</form>
```

I have jquery.form.js sending the actual post

```
var options = {
                url:          "http://localhost:8080/TestingTomcat/someClassName",
                type:         "POST",
                success:      function (html){
                    $("#placeholder").html(html);
                    change_active("comparison_page");
                }
        };

        $("#compareForm1").submit(function () {
            $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);

            return false;
        });
```

Actual Post data:

```
POSTDATA =-----------------------------153501500631101
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="isTransform"

true
-----------------------------153501500631101
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="isTransform"

true
-----------------------------153501500631101--
```

And the result I get with the button clicked or unclicked is:

```
parameter: null
```

Comment: When it is ajax call don't you need to append the param& value to URL? Ajax calls are not full form submits.

Comment: I am relatively new to ajax... I had assumed since the file sent fine I should be able to do something simple like a check box in the same way

Comment: For simple test try this, http://localhost:8080/TestingTomcat/someClassName?isTransform=false in url section

Comment: Hey hey! It worked great but this leads me to another question. If I want to submit an entire form do I have to append it to the url?  Shouldn't there be some way to encode it into a POST request?

Comment: Ajax submits partial form data (which you want to update). If you want full form, don't do ajax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parameters post from 'multipart/form-data' form can not be get from getParameter method. You should use 3rd-party library to handle the multipart data for parse the content of req.getInputStream() by yourself. I think [Apache Commons fileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/using.html) will help you.